# Trying to pass a dictionary as in a function as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, codable, weather-api

I am trying to pass a dictionary as a parameter in a function. I am currently building a small weather app.  The problem I am having is trying to get and parse the JSON data.  I have done a Weather app before and used Alamofire but I want to move away from using podfiles.  The function for Alamofire is the following:

```
func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success! Got the weather data")
            let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(weatherJSON)
            self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)

        } else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            self.cityLabel.text = "Connection Issues"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use codable and decoder to have access to the JSON data.  The problem I am having is getting is setting the JSONURLString variable.

```
private func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {
    let JsonURLString:[String: String] = [url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: parameters]
    print(JsonURLString)
    guard let url = URL(string: JsonURLString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { ( data, response, err ) in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let city = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
                self.weatherData.city = city.name
            } catch {
                print(error)
                self.cityLabel.text = "Connection issues"
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The API I am using is from [openweatherAPI](https://openweathermap.org/current) .  Below is a function that gets the current location.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
        print("longitude = \(location.coordinate.longitude), latitude = \(location.coordinate.latitude)")

        let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
        let params : [String : String] = ["lat" : latitude, "lon" : longitude, "appid" : APP_ID]
        getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: params)

    }
}
```

The problem is that above function is not going to work as I am unable to parseJSON from the openweatherAPI.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let JsonURLString:[String: String]` should be let `JsonURLString:[String: Any]`, because your parameters is already a dictionary.

Correct line of code should like below

`let JsonURLString:[String: Any] = ["url": WEATHER_URL, "parameters": parameters]`

Comment: Thanks for that Duy.  Now I am getting another error on the line ```guard let url = URL(string: JsonURLString) else { return }```. The error is ```Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'String'```

Comment: correct, you now have JsonURLString as `[String:Any]`, not `String`

If you are going to do REST call to URL like `http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2`, you need to manually create the URL in another approach.


`let queryStringParams = [ "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"]
var queryStrings : [String] = []
for key in queryStringParams.keys {
    queryStrings.append(key + "=" + queryStringParams[key]!);
}

let url = "http://example.com?" + queryStrings.joined(separator: "&")`

Comment: Will try this later